# jackson-dataformat-xml 2.10.0 Missing from Maven Central

Tags: jackson

Jackson 2.10.0 was [released today](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.10); I see the jars in central (e.g. databind), but the latest jar for dataformat-xml is 2.10.0.pr3.

-csv too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see [there is an open issue on sonatype](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-51881), perhaps related.

The problem has been resolved; the jars are there now.